# how to get details from the user using oauth?

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, oauth-2.0

how to get the details from user using OAuth? I want to get data from logged users such as user id, address, and telephone. I can do it easily using php session like this :

```php
<?php
//i create this code as simple as i can, below is just a preview of my entire code
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//search user matched with $username and $password
//starting session
session_start();

//fetching matched data using loop
$_SESSION['id'] = $row->id;
$_SESSION['phone'] = $row->phone;
$_SESSION['address'] = $row->addres;
```

My question is, how can i get the user details using OAuth in laravel restAPI?

Comment: Why you need `$_POST `, `session_start()`, and `$_SESSION ` in Laravel?

Comment: @Wahyu Kristianto i said using php session its mean native php not laravel, my question is getting user detail in laravel restAPI, im creating an API for my app now 

Answer (score 2):

You could use this to get the details of the user who is currently logged in.

```
   Auth::guard('guard-name')->user()
```

More details could be found here -- [Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel includes an authentication guard that will automatically validate API tokens on incoming requests. You only need to specify the `auth:api` middleware on any route that requires a valid access token:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user(); // get user detail
});
```

[Visit documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)